# Select a column in a multiple headers dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with multiple headers :

```
multicol = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('France', '2017'), ('France', '2018'),('UK', '2017'), ('UK', '2018')], names = ("Country", "Year"))
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 5, 8], [2, 4, 2, 9]], index=['Number', 'Volume'], columns=multicol)
```

I want to print only the column France for 2018.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tuple for select columns in `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df[('France','2018')]
print (df)
Number    2
Volume    4
Name: (France, 2018), dtype: int64
```

For more complicated selects use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
a = df.loc['Number', idx['France','2018']]
print (a)
2

b = df.loc['Number', idx[:,'2018']]
print (b)
Country  Year
France   2018    2
UK       2018    8
Name: Number, dtype: int64

c = df.loc[:, idx[:,'2017']]
print (c)
Country France   UK
Year      2017 2017
Number       1    5
Volume       2    2
```